# New line in paragraph when Enter is pressed in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElementById('area').onkeyup=keydown;
function keydown (event) {
if (event.target.id=='area' && event.which==13) {
document.getElementById('arsh').innerHTML+="\n";
     }
}
```

Arsh is the ID of my paragraph where i want to add the new line why is this not working can anyone help me ?I just want to add a new line when Enter is pressed in the textarea (ID area) to my Paragraph (ID arsh).

here is the HTML

```
<textarea ID="area" class="in">
Message
</textarea>
<br />
<br />
<p ID="tiesh" class="sh">
</p>
<br />
<br />
<p ID="arsh" class="sh">
</p>
<br />
</div>
```

I am basically trying to do it like here in stackoverflow when you press enter in the textarea down the paragraph jumps down a line also.

[image]

Comment: isn't enter key already creating a new line in a textarea?

Comment: in the textarea yes but i want it to create in the paragraph called arsh ID

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: This is a very small part of the code but its not working here

Comment: @CsakZoli It's working for me. Inspect the paragraph and you will see the newlines. http://jsfiddle.net/afgtB/

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enoughe i have a Textarea in there everything works fine my problem is below the textarea i have a paragraph that should be showing the value of the textarea but when i press enter it only brakes in the textarea but nothing happens in the paragraph.

Comment: Have you figured the solution yet ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using CSS, give `#arsh` (or any other elements that you want to render new lines) this attribute.

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Comment: close it works is there any way to make the text go to the right cuz its in the center now ?

Comment: add the property `text-align: right` in CSS. There is no such thing as *closing* unless the question doesn't fit the community guidelines. Simply mark this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('arsh').innerHTML=document.getElementById("area").value.replace(/\n/g,'<br />')
```

this will do the job

Answer (score 1):

The newline character (\n) do not render as new lines on the screen. You probably need to add an HTML break instead:

```
document.getElementById('arsh').innerHTML+="<br />";
```

Comment: First decide - do you want an HTML break, or a newline break. You need to know what the difference is.

Comment: i want a new line brake thats why i was trying to do it whit "\n" but i want this to work in the paragraph below the textarea

Comment: Next, you need to use a debugger to find out whether the enter key is being trapped. Google for Firebug (Firefox), Chrome debugger or IE debugger, depending on your browser. Alternatively, add the code alert('hi') before the line of code that adds the newline. Then run the code and see if the alert is called.

Comment: Are you aware that "\n" does not render as a newline on the screen?

Comment: but how did they do this here in stackoverflow ?when you press enter in the textarea down below in the paragraph goes to a new line to

Comment: The stackoverflow comment editor is much more complicated than your piece of code. It renders each paragraph in a separate div I believe.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><?php echo $row['description_text'];?></p>
```

Comment: The question was for javascript why would I use PHP?

Comment: bec its esey more than js

Comment: this worked for me without js. wonder why people downvoted just because it belonged to js group.